# Extrapolating in R using growth rates from another column (using dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, panel, extrapolation

I am trying to extrapolate forwards for missing values after the last non-missing value in a series using the growth rate given in another column.

This is a toy example below. My data is grouped according to product and region and should be arranged by year within grouping. I have sales data with some NA values. I am interested in using the World.growth rate to extrapolate the NA values for sales which appear after the last non-missing value in each series. So say for example Product = 1, Region = 1, I want the Interpolated.sales for 1973 to be 1972 value * World.growth value given in 1973.

Here is my data:

```
> library(openxlsx)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> sales.data <- read.xlsx("\\Interpolate_sales.xlsx", sheet = 1)
> 
> print(sales.data)
   Product Region Year      Sales World.growth Extrapolated.sales
1        1      1 1970         NA         0.88                 NA
2        1      1 1971 141.906913         0.72         141.906913
3        1      1 1972   9.605398         1.01           9.605398
4        1      1 1973         NA         1.18          11.334370
5        1      1 1974         NA         0.84           9.520871
6        1      2 1970  60.062486         0.88          60.062486
7        1      2 1971 124.904150         0.72         124.904150
8        1      2 1972         NA         1.01         126.153191
9        1      2 1973         NA         1.18         148.860765
10       1      2 1974         NA         0.84         125.043043
11       1      2 1975         NA         1.23         153.802943
12       1      3 1970  63.298780         0.88          63.298780
13       1      3 1971  90.219126         0.72          90.219126
14       1      3 1972 107.271043         1.01         107.271043
15       1      3 1973 129.122561         1.18         129.122561
16       1      3 1974         NA         0.84         108.462951
```

This is my dplyr attempt (Is there perhaps a better way by writing a function or something? I guess this will also be handy if I want to backwards extrapolate missing values at the start of a series.)

```
> sales.data.extrapolated <- sales.data %>%
+   group_by(Product, Region) %>%
+   arrange(Product, Region, Year) %>%
+   mutate(Extrapolated.sales.manual = case_when(
+     row_number() > max(which(!is.na(Sales))) ~ lag(Sales) * World.growth,
+     TRUE ~ Sales
+   ))
> 
> print(sales.data.extrapolated)
# A tibble: 16 × 7
# Groups:   Product, Region [3]
   Product Region  Year  Sales World.growth Extrapolated.sales Extrapolated.sales.manual
     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>              <dbl>                     <dbl>
 1       1      1  1970  NA            0.88              NA                        NA   
 2       1      1  1971 142.           0.72             142.                      142.  
 3       1      1  1972   9.61         1.01               9.61                      9.61
 4       1      1  1973  NA            1.18              11.3                      11.3 
 5       1      1  1974  NA            0.84               9.52                     NA   
 6       1      2  1970  60.1          0.88              60.1                      60.1 
 7       1      2  1971 125.           0.72             125.                      125.  
 8       1      2  1972  NA            1.01             126.                      126.  
 9       1      2  1973  NA            1.18             149.                       NA   
10       1      2  1974  NA            0.84             125.                       NA   
11       1      2  1975  NA            1.23             154.                       NA   
12       1      3  1970  63.3          0.88              63.3                      63.3 
13       1      3  1971  90.2          0.72              90.2                      90.2 
14       1      3  1972 107.           1.01             107.                      107.  
15       1      3  1973 129.           1.18             129.                      129.  
16       1      3  1974  NA            0.84             108.                      108.
```

As you can see, this only calculates the value for the first missing value and none beyond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "reduction" problem and must be done step-wise, since "this row's" new value depends on the results of "last row's" value ... the normal vectorized operations in R don't know the updated value for the previous value until after the whole vector has been calculated.

For this, I'll use `Reduce`, though `purrr::accumulate` is nearly a drop-in replacement if you're already using `purrr`.

```r
sales.data %>%
  group_by(Product, Region) %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = Reduce(function(prevval, ind) coalesce(Sales[ind], prevval * World.growth[ind]),
                    row_number(), init = NA, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 × 7
#    Product Region  Year  Sales World.growth Extrapolated.sales newcol
#      <int>  <int> <int>  <dbl>        <dbl>              <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1       1      1  1970  NA            0.88              NA     NA   
#  2       1      1  1971 142.           0.72             142.   142.  
#  3       1      1  1972   9.61         1.01               9.61   9.61
#  4       1      1  1973  NA            1.18              11.3   11.3 
#  5       1      1  1974  NA            0.84               9.52   9.52
#  6       1      2  1970  60.1          0.88              60.1   60.1 
#  7       1      2  1971 125.           0.72             125.   125.  
#  8       1      2  1972  NA            1.01             126.   126.  
#  9       1      2  1973  NA            1.18             149.   149.  
# 10       1      2  1974  NA            0.84             125.   125.  
# 11       1      2  1975  NA            1.23             154.   154.  
# 12       1      3  1970  63.3          0.88              63.3   63.3 
# 13       1      3  1971  90.2          0.72              90.2   90.2 
# 14       1      3  1972 107.           1.01             107.   107.  
# 15       1      3  1973 129.           1.18             129.   129.  
# 16       1      3  1974  NA            0.84             108.   108.
```

Walkthrough:

- `Reduce` is called either `nrows-1` times (if `init=` is not provided) or `nrows` if it is provided;
- the first time it is called, `prevval` is set to the `init=` value we provided (`NA`) and `ind` is `1` (the first from `row_number()`);

  - if you're curious, had we omitted `init=` completely, then on the first iteration, `prevval` would be `1` and `ind` would be `2`, the first two values in `row_number()`; not what we want
  - the *intent* when using this is that `prevval` is the previous row's `Sales`, and `ind` is the row number ... they are different "types" of numbers, not to be intermingled, which is why having `prevval=1, ind=2` was a problem
- the `coalesce(..)` calculates the expected (extrapolated) new value, but only uses it if `Sales[ind]` is `NA`; that is, `coalesce` returns (vector-wise in general, though here it is always length-1) the first non-`NA` value of the arguments provided
- the return value of that `coalesce` becomes the `prevval` on the *next* iteration of the anon-function (which `ind` now being incremented, since we used `row_number()`.
- normally, `Reduce` gives you the last value of the iterations, but we want every step of the way, so we add `accumulate=TRUE`;
- because we used `init=`, the return vector is actually length `nrows+1`, and we know that the first is a throw-away (because we used `init=`), so we remove it with `[-1]`

The `purrr::accumulate` version, if you're curious:

```r
sales.data %>%
  group_by(Product, Region) %>%
  mutate(
    newcol = purrr::accumulate(row_number(),
        ~ coalesce(Sales[.y], .x * World.growth[.y]), .init=NA)[-1]
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Moving the `row_number()` as the first argument, using `.init=` as we did `init=`, and keeping `[-1]` as before.